# (C) using strtok() for space-delimited substrings?

Tags: c, string, pointers, strtok

C noobie. I'm trying to split a string 'files' into substrings delimited by spaces and put all of the new substrings into a 2d array, 'file_array'.

The error with the current code: The 2d array is being filled up with a few random characters before each string in the new 2d array. The 2d array also isn't being filled up with all of the substrings from 'files' (I know this from doing test prints).

Sorry for the lack of comments -- the formatting isn't working.

```
int submit_files(char files[]){


        char file_array[20][50];
        char *file;
        int i = 0;
        file = strtok(files, " ");

        while(file != NULL){
             strcat(file_array[i], file);
             file = strtok(NULL, " ");
             i++;
        }


        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `memset(file_array, 0x0, sizeof(file_array))` after declaration.

Comment: You need to initialise file_array's elements. (set the first character to `\0`. You don't need `strcat`; `strcpy` would be fine. Also this code is incredibly unsafe, with two possible and unchecked buffer overflows.

Comment: @auselen's suggestion also works, but is slight overkill! Only the first characters need to be set for each element in the array. The rest are OK to stay as rubbish.

Comment: If you're lazy you can just do `char file_array[20][50] = {0};`. The compiler might complain but it'll set it all 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int submit_files(char files[])
{
    char file_array[20][50];
    char *file;
    int i = 0;
    for (file = strtok(files, " "); file && i < 20; file = strtok(NULL, " "), i++)
    {
         strncpy(file_array[i], file, 50);
    }
    for (; i < 20; ++i)
    {
         *file_array[i] = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```